# Suppress the extra white space from compiling in R

Tags: r, sage

Whenever I compile my R code, I get a lot of extra white spaces that just clog up my worksheet.

Is there any way to suppress this, without changing the code to be on the same line using semicolons? I'm currently working in `Sage Worksheets`, on the cloud.

Comment: `gsub('','',myworksheet)` ?  What do you mean by "clog up" and why does it matter?

Comment: I have various functions that I define in a cell. There is no need to output anything in that particular cell, but the worksheet creates an output of many blank lines that makes the worksheet lag. gsub did not work.

Answer (score 1):

I've made some changes to slightly reduce whitespace in R mode for SageMathCloud (https://cloud.sagemath.com); restart your project to get this update.  However, due to how Sage works they might not be sufficient. If you evaluate the following in a cell (in sage mode, or put %sage at the top), it will eliminate a lot of additional whitespace in %r mode.

```
def r_eval0(*args, **kwds):
    return sage.interfaces.r.R.eval(sage.interfaces.r.r, *args, **kwds).strip().replace('\n\n','')
sage_salvus.r_eval0 = r_eval0
```